# I'm trying to hide a scrollView, and it isn't hiding

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, show-hide

Ok this is embarrassingly simple of a question, but I just can't get this to work right! I have two uiscrollviews that I have hooked up everywhere in IB. On viewDidLoad, I want only the first one to be visible. So I mkae the two scrollViews:

```
    [scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollView1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scrollView1.clipsToBounds = NO;    // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;

scrollView1.minimumZoomScale = 1;
scrollView1.maximumZoomScale = 5;
scrollView1.delegate = self;
[scrollView1 setScrollEnabled:YES];

imageView31 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:firstImage];

[scrollView1 addSubview:imageView31];
//[scrollView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 660)];


[scrollView2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollView2 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scrollView2.clipsToBounds = NO;    // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
scrollView2.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;

scrollView2.minimumZoomScale = 1;
scrollView2.maximumZoomScale = 5;
scrollView2.delegate = self;
[scrollView2 setScrollEnabled:YES];

imageView32 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:firstImage];

[scrollView2 addSubview:imageView32];
```

and then in order to just show the first one, I do this:

```
scrollView2.hidden == YES;
```

But its still there when I load!!!

Anybody know whats going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
scrollView2.hidden = YES;  // one equals sign
```

The double-equals is doing a comparison, not an assignment, and it's basically not accomplishing anything.